# Bean Validation Groups - Validating inner classes

Tags: java, validation

I trying to validate B.name only in ValidateZZ.class group by this code

```
@GroupSequence({A.class, ValidateZZ.class})
class A {
    @NotNull(group = ValidateZZ.class)
    String name;

    @Valid
    B classB;
}

@Validate
class B {
    @NotNull(group = ValidateZZ.class)
    String name;
}
```

But it is not work! A.name is validated well, but a.classB.name not validated.
Obviously I do something wrong. How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem that way:

```
private <T> void validateFormData(T formData, Class<T> clazz, LoanApplicationIo loanApplication) {
    List<Class> groups = Arrays.stream(clazz.getAnnotations())
        .filter(annotation -> annotation instanceof GroupSequence)
        .flatMap(annotation -> Arrays.stream(((GroupSequence)annotation).value()))
        .filter(Class::isInterface)
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (!groups.contains(Default.class)) {
        groups.add(Default.class);
    }

    Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations = validator.validate(formData, groups.toArray(new Class[groups.size()]));
```

I'am not shure about is the right way, but it works.